# directx error LNK2019 c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, directx

i'm using visual studio 2010, and i try to run old code, developed in visual studio 2005, and I got errors associated to direct x libraries .i cant find online a solution for the link error about directX.

here is the output:

1>Boxes.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Direct3DRMCreate@4 referenced in function "private: void **thiscall CBoxes::CreateD3D(void)" (?CreateD3D@CBoxes@@AAEXXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _DirectDrawCreate@12 referenced in function "int __cdecl CreateDirectDraw(struct HWND** *,int,int,int,int)" (?CreateDirectDraw@@YAHPAUHWND__@@HHHH@Z)
1>Sound.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _DirectSoundCreate@12 referenced in function "public: int **thiscall CSound::Create(struct HWND** *)" (?Create@CSound@@QAEHPAUHWND__@@@Z)
1>Sound.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__mmioSetInfo@12 referenced in function "private: int __thiscall CSound::LoadWaveFile(char *,struct tWAVEFORMATEX * *,unsigned char * *,unsigned int *)" (?LoadWaveFile@CSound@@AAEHPADPAPAUtWAVEFORMATEX@@PAPAEPAI@Z)
1>Sound.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__mmioAdvance@12 referenced in function "private: int __thiscall CSound::LoadWaveFile(char *,struct tWAVEFORMATEX * *,unsigned char * *,unsigned int *)" (?LoadWaveFile@CSound@@AAEHPADPAPAUtWAVEFORMATEX@@PAPAEPAI@Z)
1>Sound.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__mmioGetInfo@12 referenced in function "private: int __thiscall CSound::LoadWaveFile(char *,struct tWAVEFORMATEX * *,unsigned char * *,unsigned int *)" (?LoadWaveFile@CSound@@AAEHPADPAPAUtWAVEFORMATEX@@PAPAEPAI@Z)
1>Sound.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__mmioAscend@12 referenced in function "private: int __thiscall CSound::LoadWaveFile(char *,struct tWAVEFORMATEX * *,unsigned char * *,unsigned int *)" (?LoadWaveFile@CSound@@AAEHPADPAPAUtWAVEFORMATEX@@PAPAEPAI@Z)
1>Sound.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__mmioRead@12 referenced in function "private: int __thiscall CSound::LoadWaveFile(char *,struct tWAVEFORMATEX * *,unsigned char * *,unsigned int *)" (?LoadWaveFile@CSound@@AAEHPADPAPAUtWAVEFORMATEX@@PAPAEPAI@Z)
1>Sound.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__mmioClose@8 referenced in function "private: int __thiscall CSound::LoadWaveFile(char *,struct tWAVEFORMATEX * *,unsigned char * *,unsigned int *)" (?LoadWaveFile@CSound@@AAEHPADPAPAUtWAVEFORMATEX@@PAPAEPAI@Z)
1>Sound.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__mmioDescend@16 referenced in function "private: int __thiscall CSound::LoadWaveFile(char *,struct tWAVEFORMATEX * *,unsigned char * *,unsigned int *)" (?LoadWaveFile@CSound@@AAEHPADPAPAUtWAVEFORMATEX@@PAPAEPAI@Z)
1>Sound.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__mmioOpenA@12 referenced in function "private: int __thiscall CSound::LoadWaveFile(char *,struct tWAVEFORMATEX * *,unsigned char * *,unsigned int *)" (?LoadWaveFile@CSound@@AAEHPADPAPAUtWAVEFORMATEX@@PAPAEPAI@Z)
1>c:\users\shir\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\terraFly\Debug\terraFly.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 11 unresolved externals

Does anyone have a suggestion how to fix it?

thanks,
shir

Comment: i cant find online a solution for the link error about directX.

Comment: Which version of the DirectX SDK are you trying to use for this old code? Note that ``Direct3DRMCreate`` is Direct3D Retained Mode which dates back to DirectX 3. It is not supported on modern versions of Windows (Windows Vista or later). See [KB969150](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/969150)